# I get an error: bad window path name ".!frame" when i press a button in the following code?

Tags: python, tkinter, destroy

I am trying to make two different screens and link them with each other using a button on each screen assigned respected functions to them as command.

Please help me to know why I get the following error :

> bad window path name ".!frame"

when I press a button in the following code.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
my_height = 600
my_width = 350
root.geometry(f"{my_height}x{my_width}")
# root.maxsize(my_height, my_width)

# FRAMES
main_frame = Frame(root, bg="Red", borderwidth=30)
other_frame = Frame(root, bg="Yellow", borderwidth=30)


# first window
def main_screen():
    other_frame.destroy()
    Label(main_frame, text="First Window").pack()
    Button(main_frame, text="GO", command=second_screen).pack()
    main_frame.pack()


def second_screen():
    main_frame.destroy()
    Label(other_frame, text="Second Window").pack()
    Button(other_frame, text="BACK", command=main_screen).pack()
    other_frame.pack()


main_screen()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can't reuse a Frame after you've called `.destroy()` on it.  You'd have to create a new Frame each time you switch - or use `.pack_forget()` to merely hide the old Frame (in which case you'd want to create the widgets in each Frame only once, rather than on each switch).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you delete the frame `other_frame` before when you write `other_frame.destroy()`. This makes it inaccessible by the rest of the program since you destroyed it.

So there would be two solutions: One would be to, as BryanOakley mentioned, to use `.pack()`. The other would be to use `.place()`.

## Code for `.pack()`:

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
my_height = 600
my_width = 350
root.geometry(f"{my_height}x{my_width}")
# root.maxsize(my_height, my_width)
def main_screen():
    other_frame.pack_forget()
    main_frame.pack()


def second_screen():
    main_frame.pack_forget()
    other_frame.pack()

# FRAMES
main_frame = Frame(root, bg="Red", borderwidth=30)
other_frame = Frame(root, bg="Yellow", borderwidth=30)
Label(other_frame, text="Second Window").pack()
Button(other_frame, text="BACK", command=main_screen).pack()
Label(main_frame, text="First Window").pack()
Button(main_frame, text="GO", command=second_screen).pack()


# first window

main_screen()
root.mainloop()
```

## Code for `.place()`:

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
my_height = 600
my_width = 350
root.geometry(f"{my_height}x{my_width}")
# root.maxsize(my_height, my_width)


# first window
def main_screen():
    main_frame.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.1, anchor = "center")
    other_frame.place(relx = 1.5, rely = 0.1, anchor = "center")
    main_frame.update()
    other_frame.update()


def second_screen():
    main_frame.place(relx = -0.5, rely = 0.1, anchor = "center")
    main_frame.update()
    other_frame.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.1, anchor = "center")
    other_frame.update()
# FRAMES
main_frame = Frame(root, bg="Red", borderwidth=30)
other_frame = Frame(root, bg="Yellow", borderwidth=30)
main_frame.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.1, anchor = "center")
other_frame.place(relx = 1.5, rely = 0.1, anchor = "center")
Label(main_frame, text="First Window").pack()
Button(main_frame, text="GO", command=second_screen).pack()
Label(other_frame, text="Second Window").pack()
Button(other_frame, text="BACK", command=main_screen).pack()


main_screen()
root.mainloop()
```

The advantage of using `.place()` is you can animate the frame back and forth using a for loop.

## Here is the code for that:

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
my_height = 600
my_width = 350
root.geometry(f"{my_height}x{my_width}")
# root.maxsize(my_height, my_width)


# first window
def main_screen():
    global x1, y1, x2, y2
    for i in range(1000):
        x1 += 0.001
        x2 += 0.001
        main_frame.place(relx = x1, rely = y1, anchor = "center")
        other_frame.place(relx = x2, rely = y2, anchor = "center")
        main_frame.update()
        other_frame.update()
        
    

def second_screen():
    global x1, y1, x2, y2
    for i in range(1000):
        x1 -= 0.001
        x2 -= 0.001
        main_frame.place(relx = x1, rely = y1, anchor = "center")
        other_frame.place(relx = x2, rely = y2, anchor = "center")
        main_frame.update()
        other_frame.update()
    
# FRAMES
x1, y1 = 0.5, 0.1
x2, y2 = 1.5, y1
main_frame = Frame(root, bg="Red", borderwidth=30)
other_frame = Frame(root, bg="Yellow", borderwidth=30)
main_frame.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.1, anchor = "center")
other_frame.place(relx = 1.5, rely = 0.1, anchor = "center")
Label(main_frame, text="First Window").pack()
Button(main_frame, text="GO", command=second_screen).pack()
Label(other_frame, text="Second Window").pack()
Button(other_frame, text="BACK", command=main_screen).pack()



root.mainloop()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The OP is using `pack`, not `place`. Also, you are calling `update()` twice in each function, and in both cases that is completely unnecessary.

Comment: @BryanOakley The OP didn't say they don't want to use `place()`. I agree that `place` is not the best, but in this case it is the most simplistic solution. Also, if you want to animate both frames, you can slightly edit the program to achieve that.

Comment: @BryanOakley I have figured out how to do it with pack.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you do in `main_screen` is to destroy `other_frame`. When you call `second_screen`, it tries to use that frame as the parent for new widgets but it has been destroyed. That is why you get the error `bad window path name ".!frame"` - it is bad because it has been destroyed and can no longer be used.

A simple solution is to simply not call `other_frame.destroy()`. Instead, you can remove it from view with `other_frame.pack_forget()`.

It's important to know that `pack` works by placing objects in available space, and in the order that `pack` was called. If you remove and add widgets once the app has started, that may affect the order in which the widgets appear.

In this specific case, since `main_screen` and `other_screen` are the only widgets directly in root it doesn't matter, and doesn't affect the reason why you got the error you got.

Comment: The problem with this is when you pack it again, there are two buttons inside the first `main_frame`.

Comment: @10Rep the fact that there are buttons inside of `main_frame` is irrelevant, because they are in `main_frame` so they won't affect the placement of widgets in the root window. But you are correct that this is a weakness with using pack. Thanks for the comment, I'll add some clarifying information.